# Dequeuing native WordPress/WooCommerce scripts

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have to drastically shrink a WooCommerce store because of performance reasons.
Therefore I use a plugin to selectively deactivate Plugins per page/URL. This works sort-of-ok.

To find out which plugins are active, I use this code:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wsds_detect_enqueued_scripts' );
function wsds_detect_enqueued_scripts() {
  global $wp_scripts;
  foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
    echo $handle . ' | ';
  endforeach;
}
```

This way I can see the script handles.
Now I can deactivate them like this on all category pages:

```
if (is_product_category()) {
         wp_dequeue_script('handle1-js');
         wp_dequeue_script('handle2-js');
         wp_dequeue_script('handle3');
```

Now I'd like to selectively remove certain WP/WC functions, like the datepicker, or maybe even jQuery on pages where it is not needed. The above script does not list the WP/WC function handles.

What would be a good way to get them?

Answer (score 0):

```
function debug_print_scripts_styles() {

    $result = [];
    $result['scripts'] = [];
    $result['styles'] = [];

    // All loaded Scripts
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $script ) :
       $result['scripts'][] =  $wp_scripts->registered[$script]->handle . ";";
    endforeach;

    // All loaded Styles
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $style ) :
       $result['styles'][] =  $wp_styles->registered[$style]->handle . ";";
    endforeach;

    return $result;
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'debug_enqued_script_style_list');

function debug_enqued_script_style_list() {

    $all_the_scripts_and_styles = debug_print_scripts_styles();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($all_the_scripts_and_styles);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;

}
```

Add the above code snippets to your active theme functions.php to print the list of handles in the shop front.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, tried that. But it does the same as my script (plus CSS) and gives the exact same results: Only Plugin JS, no native WP/WC JS. But you gave me an interesting Idea...I completely forgot to dequeue the styles...this also saves some loading time :-)